# About App Store promo codes

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, promotion-code

I have recently released an app on the app store. I would like to allow some to have access to a free version but have some concerns about offering promo codes. My big question is:

How many times can one promo code be used? I guess I'm concerned about a promo code getting into the wrong hands and being distributed...

Thanks! V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A promo code can only be used once.  Sometime developers will post a few of them on Twitter or other marketing channels and people can grab one, however if it has already been entered, iTunes will report it as "already used".

Apple has a [good summary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ProvidingPromoCodes.html) of how promo codes work.